# Package biblatex error: Category 3 not declared ( \endentry)

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem with biblatex, I can't use some references from my document.

It is referenced that `\endentry` is missing, in biblatex manual, there is no much information how to use `\endentry` command.

How can I fix it?

> File.bbl:41: Package biblatex Error: Category '3' not declared. ( \endentry ...)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers,url=true,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
\makeatother

\def\initlist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\initlist}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\forlistloop{\DeclareBibliographyCategory}{\initlist}
\AtDataInput{\ifskipbib{}{\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

%To add square brackets in supercites
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
   \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,ifnames=1,compound=false]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,compound=false]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}

These are my references, \cite{bael}, \cite{is}, \cite{macgregor}, \cite{morales}, \cite{nationalacademy-joints}, \cite{pfeiffer}.

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5,yscale=2]
    \draw[step=5mm,help lines] (0,0) grid ((5.5,1.5);
%  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5.5,3.5);
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
  \path (3,-.5) node [rectangle]    {Período $T$ ($s$)}
        (-1,1) node [rectangle,rotate=90]    {Coeficiente $C$}
        ;

    \foreach \x in {0,2,4}
    \draw (\x cm,2pt) -- (\x cm,-2pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {.5,1,1.5}
    \draw (2pt,\y cm) -- (-2pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};


    \pgfplothandlerlineto
        \pgfplotfunction{\x}{0,.6}{\pgfpointxy{\x}{.3}} 
        \pgfplotfunction{\x}{0.6,.65,...,5.5}{\pgfpointxy{\x}{.18/\x}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke};

    \pgfplothandlerlineto
        \pgfplotfunction{\x}{0,.6}{\pgfpointxy{\x}{1.35}}
        \pgfplotfunction{\x}{0.6,.65,...,5.5}{\pgfpointxy{\x}{.81/\x}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke};

    %\draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{.81/\x})    node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

There is a bunch of references which I can't show them in my thesis~\cite{aci2011building}~\cite{american2010minimum}~\cite{elwood2009stiffness} .

\printbibheading
\foreach \letter in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}{%
  \begingroup\edef\myprintbib{\endgroup\printbibliography[category=\letter,prefixnumbers=\letter,heading=none]}\myprintbib}


\end{document}
```

My bibliography:

```
@book{morales,
    author    = {R. Morales},
    title     = {Diseño Estructural Sismorresistente},
    publisher = {Fondo Editorial ICG},
    year      = {2002},
    address   = {Lima},
    pages     = {4-5},
    }

@book{macgregor,
    author    = {J. MacGregor and J. Wight},
    title     = {Reinforced Concrete Mechanics and Design},
    publisher = {Prentice Hall},
    date      = {2011},
    location  = {Upper Saddle River, New Jersey},
    pages     = {71-71},
    }

@report{pfeiffer,
    author    = {Michael J. Pfeiffer, and David Darwin},
    title     = {Joint Design for Reinforced Concrete Buildings},
    institution = {University of Kansas Structural Engineering and Materials Laboratory},
    date      = {1987},
    location  = {Lawrence, KS},
    pages     = {73},
    }

@manual{seae,
    author    = {Departamento de Tecnología Industrial},
    title     = {Código Técnico de la Edificación. Documento Básico SE-AE Seguridad Estructural: Acciones en la Edificación},
    location  = {Madrid},
    date      = {2007},
    pages     = {9},
    }

@manual{bael,
    title    = {Règles de techniques de conception et de calcul des ouvrages et construction en béton armé suivant la méthode des états limites},
    author   = {Ministère de l'Equipement des Transports et du Logement},
    location = {Paris},
    date     = {1999},
    pages    = {86-87},
    }

@book{is,
    title    = {Plain and Reinforced Concrete - Code of Practice IS 456-2000},
    edition  = {Fourth},
    author   = {Bureau of Indian Standards},
    location = {Nueva Delhi},
    date     = {2000},
    pages    = {86-87},
    }

@report{pca-joints,
    title    = {Buildings Movements and Joints},
    author   = {Portland Cement Association},
    location = {Skokie, Illinois},
    date     = {1983},
    pages    = {36},
    }

@report{nationalacademy-joints,
    title    = {Expansion Joints in Buildings},
    author   = {Standing Commitee on Structural Engineering of the Federal Construction Council},
    number   = {Technical Report No. 65},
    institution    = {National Academy of Sciences},
    location       = {Washington},
    date           = {1974},
    pagetotal      = {43},
    }

@book{vallecilla,
    author    = {C. Ramiro Vallecilla},
    title     = {Fuerzas Sísmicas Principios y Aplicaciones NSR-98},
    publisher = {Editorial Bauen},
    location  = {Bogotá},
    date      = {2003},
    pages     = {192-201},
    }

@online{senhami,
    author          = {Servicion Nacional de Meteorología e Hidrología},
    organization    = {Ministerio del Ambiente},
    title           = {Datos Históricos},
    url             = {http://www.senamhi.gob.pe/main_mapa.php?t=dHi},
    }

@manual{e030,
    title    = {Reglamento Nacional de Edificaciones, Norma E.030 Diseño Sismorresistente},
    organization   = {Ministerio de Vivienda, Construcción y Saneamiento},
    location = {Lima},
    date     = {2006},
    }

@book{paulay1992seismic,
  title={Seismic Design of Reinforced Concrete and Masonry Buildings},
  author={Paulay, T. and Priestley, M.J.N.},
  isbn={9780471549154},
  lccn={lc91034862},
  series={Pure and applied mathematics},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Wiley}
}

@book{priestley2003myths,
  title={Myths and fallacies in earthquake engineering, revisited},
  author={Priestley, M.J.N. and Society of Earthquake and Civil Engineering Dynamics},
  lccn={2006387620},
  series={Monografia Rose School},
  year={2003},
  publisher={IUSS Press}
}

@book{priestley2007displacement,
  title={Displacement-based Seismic Design of Structures},
  author={Priestley, M.J.N. and Calvi, G.M. and Kowalsky, M.J.},
  isbn={9788861980006},
  lccn={2008382667},
  year={2007},
  publisher={IUSS Press}
}

@thesis{Rolando,
    title= {Seismic Design of Asymmetric Ductile Systems},
    author= {Castillo, Rolando},
    publisher= {University of Canterbury. Department of Civil Engineering},
    year= {2004},
    pagetotal= {340},
    location= {Christchurch, New Zealand},
    }

@book{american2010minimum,
  title={Minimum Design Loads for Buildings and Other Structures: ASCE Standard 7-10},
  author={American Society of Civil Engineers},
  isbn={9780784410851},
  lccn={2010011011},
  url={http://books.google.com.pe/books?id=i1TOe5chZJQC},
  year={2010},
  publisher={American Society of Civil Engineers}
}

@book{nsr10,
  title={Reglamento Colombiano de Construcción Sismo Resistente NSR-10},
  author={Ministerio de Ambiente, Vivienda y de Desarrollo Territorial},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Imprenta Nacional de Colombia}
}

@book{wilson1998three,
  title={Three dimensional static and dynamic analysis of structures: a physical approach with emphasis on earthquake engineering},
  author={Wilson, E.L. and Computers and Structures, Inc},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Computers and Structures Inc.}
}

%@book{mf,
%title={Building Code (ACI 218-11)},
%author={ACI Commitee 318},
%isbn={97808},
%year{2011},
%publisher={ACI}
%}
%

@book{aci2011building,
  title={Building Code Requirements for Structural Concrete (ACI 318-11 Metric) and Commentary},
  author={ACI Committee 318 and American Concrete Institute},
  isbn={9780870317453},
 year={2011},
  publisher={American Concrete Institute}
}

@report{elwood2009stiffness,
title={Effective Stiffness of Reinforced Concrete Columns},
author={Elwood, K. and Eberhard, M.O.},
journaltitle={ACI Structural Journal},
year={2009},
volume={106-S45},
pages={476-484}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry

```
@book{aci2011building,
  title={Building Code Requirements for Structural Concrete (ACI 318-11 Metric) and Commentary},
  author={ACI Committee 318 and American Concrete Institute},
  isbn={9780870317453},
 year={2011},
  publisher={American Concrete Institute}
}
```

is considered to have its first author with

- first name: American
- middle name: Committee
- last name: 318

The same for the second author. Institutional authors should be braced and a `sortkey` should be specified:

```
@book{aci2011building,
  title={Building Code Requirements for Structural Concrete (ACI 318-11 Metric) and Commentary},
  author={{ACI Committee 318} and {American Concrete Institute}},
  sortkey={ACICommittee318},
  isbn={9780870317453},
  year={2011},
  publisher={American Concrete Institute}
}
```