# Problems with numbers in author field

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I want to cite a book whose author name has numbers. The error is:

> Package biblatex Error: Category '4' not declared.

My package version is the current.

```
  @book{aci1966deflections,
  title={Deflections of Reinforced Concrete Flexural Members},
  author={ACI Committee 435},
  year={1966},
  publisher={{American Concrete Institute}}
  }
```

Any suggestion to include this kind of reference?

### Update

I think it is not the same problem which is linked for duplicating (Category 4 for Category 3). I did what the section 2.3.3 of the biblatex manual says, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Meanwhile, there's another expression in the log file:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'Desarrollo.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.3
```

Biblatex version is:

```
biblatex-dm.cfg blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
```

What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169006/package-biblatex-error-category-3-not-declared-endentry?

Comment: @egreg I wrote an update for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When BibTeX and biblatex parse the information provided in the `author` field of a given entry, the default assumption is that the field contains the names of one or more *persons*. E.g.,

```
author = "Johann Wolfgang von Goethe and Vincent van Gogh",
```

Each person's name must have at least a last name component (above: Goethe and Gogh); first names, "von" components, and "junior" components are optional. The word `and` is a *keyword* that serves to separate individual authors' names. BibTeX and biblatex usually do a good job parsing a personal author's name into its constituent components.

However, if the entry's author is not one or more persons but, rather, a *corporate entity*, the parsing routines employed by BibTeX and biblatex are almost certainly going to produce gibberish. In the case of the entry you've posted, the parsing algorithm will conclude that the author's first name is `ACI`, the middle name is `Committee`, and the last name is `435`. No joke! Clearly this isn't what you want to happen.

Fortunately, an easy remedy is available: To instruct BibTeX and biblatex not to perform any parsing on the contents of the author field, i.e., to treat it as one long string, encase the corporate author's name in a second pair of curly braces.

```
author={{ACI Committee 435}},
```

In effect, the entry's author field will now be treated as consisting of one last name.) As a result, the entry will be sorted under `A` and authoryear-type citations will look like "ACI Committee 435 (1966)" rather than like "435 (1966)"...

Comment: +1 See also section 2.3.3 of the biblatex manual

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes I did, and I got it. But is weird because doesn't work. There's another expression in the log file: `Package biblatex Warning: File 'Desarrollo.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.3.` Biblatex version is `biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)`

Comment: @isai - Have you tried deleting the `.bbl` file by hand and the rerunning LaTeX and biber on the main file?

Comment: @Mico Hi, thanks for your response. I don't understand where I can find my `.bbl` file, do you talk about that, right?

Comment: @Isai - the file `Desarrollo.bbl` should be in the same directory as `Desarrollo.tex`.

Comment: @Mico I'm sorry, but there are only: `.bib`, `.tex` and my `.pdf`.

Comment: @Isai - so where's the file `Desarollo.bbl`?

Comment: @Mico Same question.

Comment: @Mico I found the problem; I updated only `biblatex`file, but it is important to updated the related files, now I can see my references.

Comment: @Isai - delighted that things are working smoothly now.